# Spring boot controller + thymeleaf page refresh

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am developing a dashboard page which will parse files and generate charts. So when I click submit button, I want that page should get reloaded or refreshed after successful post method. I have enabled security also, but disabled csrf().

Here is my controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/analyze.go", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String analyze(@RequestParam("logFile") MultipartFile file) { 
        //my code

        return "{}";
        //return "redirect:dashboard.html"; 
    }
```

Here is my thymeleaf template named as dashboard.html,

```
    <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/analyze.go}"
                                method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="logFile">File input</label> <input type="file"
                                        name="logFile" id="logFile"/>
                                    <p class="help-block">Select only *.log or any text type of
                                        files</p>                                       
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                            </form>
```

Currently it is redirecting to http://localhost:9090/analyze.go page. Any idea how to overcome this issue. I tried with returning "redirect:redirect_page" but it is not working.

Comment: Does the user has permission to navigate to dashboard?  your view resolver should resolve to dashboard.html

Comment: I found the solution using return RedirectView

Comment: For better visibility to other users who face same issue can you paste your solution so that others can use it